# codeigniter multiple table records in one vie

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, multiple-columns

If I have in one table data in columns: id_first, name. Example:

```
1, Joe
2, MIchael
3, Kim
```

And in second have data in columns id_second, id_first, lastname. Example"

```
1, 3, Basinger
2, 3, Basinger
3, 1, Jordan
4. 2, Arena
```

To get data in view like this:

```
1, Kim, Basinger
2, Kim, Basinger
3, Joe, Jordan
4, Michael, Arena
```

How to write all Model, View and Controller? Can be solution in JOIN, which I don't know?

Comment: Have a look at MySql joins.

Comment: CodeIgniter has a join function for database http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html